# Server Error in '/Ebpp3' Application

Tags: asp.net

At my company we have a single machine that recieves this error message once a button on a certain website is pressed. The website itself seems to work fine (except for not loading a few pictures) but once the button is pressed the machine recieves this error.

Server Error in '/Ebpp3' Application

I've checked it on IE and Firefox. Already tried capability mode which didn't work.

```
Stack Trace:


[HttpException (0x80004005): Authentication of viewstate failed.  1) If this is a cluster, edit <machineKey> configuration so all servers use the same validationKey and validation algorithm.  AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.  2) Viewstate can only be posted back to the same page.  3) The viewstate for this page might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.LosFormatter.Deserialize(String input) +117
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +101

[HttpException (0x80004005): Invalid_Viewstate
    Client IP: 100.3.103.37
    Port: 51747
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
    ViewState: 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
    Http-Referer: https://www.sdctreastax.com/ebpp3/(dolptk45bmjvq245ufgdhr45)/Start.aspx/Start.aspx
    Path: /ebpp3/Start.aspx/Search.Aspx.]
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +447
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageViewState() +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +447
```

Comment: The website is controller by whom? You or somebody else?

Comment: Have you tried these troubleshooting steps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829743 ?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your problem is caused by the page posting back to a page other than itself.

`Path: /ebpp3/Start.aspx/Search.Aspx.`

`Http-Referer: https://www.sdctreastax.com/ebpp3/(dolptk45bmjvq245ufgdhr45)/Start.aspx/Start.aspx`

If you need to do a cross page postback you need to be sure you're using the [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property.

> The PostBackUrl property allows you to perform a cross-page post using
>   the Button control.